# how to unwrap PostgreSQL connection from the IBM WSJdbc41Connection

Tags: postgresql, connection, websphere-liberty

I have been trying to unwrap PostgreSQL connection from the IBM JNDI (WebSphere liberty ) and have had no luck please any help with that :

```
         Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/indi");
        Connection cnx = dataSource.getConnection();
```

I get this exception :

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException:
     com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection cannot be cast to
     org.postgresql.PGConnection
```

I tried :

```
if(cnx.isWrapperFor(PGConnectionPoolDataSource.class)) {
        //unwrap
    }
    if (cnx.isWrapperFor(org.postgresql.ds.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4SimpleDataSource.class)) {
            //unwrap
    }

    if (cnx.isWrapperFor(org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.class)) {
            //unwrap
    }
    if (cnx.isWrapperFor(org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.class)) {
            //unwrap
    }
    if (cnx.isWrapperFor(org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.class)) {
            //unwrap
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to unwrap a JDBC object (DataSource, Connection, etc) to a vendor-specific interface, the JDBC driver in the configured `<datSource>` must be available to the application classloader.  The configuration will look something like this:

```
<application location="oraclejdbcfat.war" >
    <!-- expose the 'DBLib' containing the JDBC driver jar to the app classloader -->
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="DBLib"/>
</application>

<library id="DBLib">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/postgresql/" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/myDS">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DBLib"/>
    <properties .../>
</dataSource>
```

From there, you can unwrap the object in the same way you were doing before, namely:

```
DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/myDS");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
PGConnection pgConn = conn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class);
```

---

Also, there is an `enableConnectionCasting` boolean attribute on `<dataSource>` configuration which will automatically call unwrap for you upon `getConnection()`.

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/myDS" enableConnectionCasting="true">
```

Then the java code is a bit simpler:

```
DataSource ds = InitialContext.lookup("jdbc/indi");
PGConnection pgConn = (PGConnection) ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Hey Andy . I tired the first option and got  java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isWrapperFor(Class<?>) is not yet implemented.

Comment: second option :  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47 cannot be cast to org.postgresql.PGConnection

Comment: the `Connection.isWrapperFor(Class<?>)` class has been in the JDBC spec since 4.0 (several years), and I can see in the postgresql code that they do implement this method:  https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL9_4_1201/org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java#L251
So this implies you are using a really old version of the postresql JDBC driver and need to update to a newer version

Comment: make sense I'm using 9.1 I will update it and check again

Comment: Andy do u have any idea how I ca get these classes

Comment: private static final String JDBC_ADAPTER_CONNECTION_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection";

 private static final String JDBC_ADAPTER_UTIL_NAME = "com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil";

Comment: those classes are liberty internals and are not meant to be used by the application

Comment: Thanks Andy for help I tried all the options and no luck to unwrap liberty connection . However , I believe we can use these options with WAS

Comment: There must be a duplicate set of postgresql classes somewhere... perhaps packaged inside of your application under WEB-INF/lib?