# How to get oracle connection from hibernate connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am trying to get oracle connection from hibernate. below is the code that I am using.

```
server.xml

<library id="jdbcDriverFiles">
    <fileset dir="libraries" includes="ojdbc7.jar" />
</library>

<dataSource id="x" jndiName="jndisce"
    statementCacheSize="20" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <containerAuthData password="Pwd" user="User" />
    <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" libraryRef="jdbcDriverFiles" />
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="600"
        connectionTimeout="180" maxIdleTime="1800" maxPoolSize="70"
        minPoolSize="1" purgePolicy="EntirePool" reapTime="180" />
    <properties.oracle
        URL="url"
        password="Pwd" portNumber="123" serverName="server"
        user="User" />
</dataSource>   

<webApplication id="cm" location="cm.war"
    name="cm">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="jdbcDriverFiles" />
</webApplication>

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jndisce");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
OracleConnection con = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

and below is the error that I am getting.

```
java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection@7acaddcd does not 
wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Hibernate, you are not even using a Hibernate API here. You are trying to unwrap an OracleConnection from a IBM datasource connection but apparently it does not let you do this. According to the following article, this might be due to class loader issues: [how to unwrap PostgreSQL connection from the IBM WSJdbc41Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286768/how-to-unwrap-postgresql-connection-from-the-ibm-wsjdbc41connection)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you help me little more with the above problem. Iam using WAS server. How can I get the oracle connection from WAS.

Comment: Did you read the answer of the question that I wrote in my answer? Did you try setting the `enableConnectionCasting` attribute in the `dataSource` element? Are you sure cm.war does not contain the jdbc driver?